# Esperar a que termine una aplicación de shell

Tags: shell, vb6

Tengo que esperar que termine la ejecución, o aunque sea controlar si se ha colgado o no a la hora de ejecutar una aplicación mediante el SHELL.

He estado indagando, y me he topado con https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/305368/how-to-wait-for-a-shelled-application-to-finish-by-using-visual-basic, que me proporciona lo que necesito, pero el caso es que estoy en VB 6.0, y no me sirve el código.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Si la pregunta es sobre vb6, no tiene sentido la etiqueta vb.net. A pesar de compartir nombre, son dos lenguajes diferentes.

Answer (score 3):

Una forma es interactuar con la API de Windows: [`CreateProcessA()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) para inicial la ejecución de un determinado proceso, puede ser de consola o gráfico, luego para esperar la finalización del comando, hay que usar [`WaitForSingleObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) para verificar si el proceso está activo y si es así esperarlo. En caso de querer implementar un "timeout" para el comando, habrá que implementar un timer para controlar el tiempo y usar [`TerminateProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx) para finalizarlo.

Una implementación sencilla podría ser la siguiente:

```
Private Type PROCESS_INFORMATION
  hProcess As Long
  hThread As Long
  dwProcessId As Long
  dwThreadID As Long
End Type

Private Type STARTUPINFO
  cb As Long
  lpReserved As String
  lpDesktop As String
  lpTitle As String
  dwX As Long
  dwY As Long
  dwXSize As Long
  dwYSize As Long
  dwXCountChars As Long
  dwYCountChars As Long
  dwFillAttribute As Long
  dwFlags As Long
  wShowWindow As Integer
  cbReserved2 As Integer
  lpReserved2 As Long
  hStdInput As Long
  hStdOutput As Long
  hStdError As Long
End Type
Private Declare Function CreateProcessA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpApplicationName As Long, ByVal lpCommandLine As String, ByVal lpProcessAttributes As Long, ByVal lpThreadAttributes As Long, ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, ByVal lpEnvironment As Long, ByVal lpCurrentDirectory As Long, lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Long
Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function TerminateProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByVal uExitCode As Long) As Long

Public Function Execute(Path As String, Optional Parameters As String = "", Optional Wait As Boolean = False, Optional Hide As Boolean = False, Optional TimeOut As Integer = -1) As Long

  Const STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW As Long = &H1
  Const SW_HIDE As Long = 0

  Dim proc As PROCESS_INFORMATION
  Dim startup As STARTUPINFO
  Dim Ret As Long
  Dim CmdLine As String
  Dim ExecuteTask As Long
  Dim elapsed_time As Double

  CmdLine = Path
  If Trim(Parameters) <> "" Then
    CmdLine = CmdLine & " """ & Parameters & """"
  End If

  startup.cb = Len(startup)
  If Hide Then
     startup.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
     startup.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE
  End If

  start_time = Timer
  Ret = CreateProcessA(0&, CmdLine, 0&, 0&, 1&, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0&, 0&, startup, proc)
  ExecuteTask = proc.hProcess
  If Wait Then
    elapsed_time = Timer - start_time
    While IsTaskRunning(ExecuteTask) And (TimeOut <= 0 Or elapsed_time < TimeOut)
      DoEvents
      elapsed_time = Timer - start_time
    Wend
    If IsTaskRunning(ExecuteTask) Then
        TerminateProcess ExecuteTask, -1&
    End If
  End If

End Function
Public Function IsTaskRunning(taskID As Long) As Boolean

  Dim Ret As Long

  If taskID = 0 Then Exit Function
  Ret = WaitForSingleObject(taskID, 0)
  IsTaskRunning = (Ret <> 0)
  If Not IsTaskRunning Then
    Ret = CloseHandle(taskID)
    taskID = 0
  End If

End Function
```

Para probar la nueva rutina `Execute()`, invocando a la línea de comando como proceso podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Execute "cmd.exe", , True, , 10 ' Ejecución con timeout de 10 segundos
    Execute "cmd.exe", , True       ' Ejecución con espera
    MsgBox "Fin de la ejecución"
End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, probare a Implementarlo en el codigo a ver si funciona!

Answer (score 0):

Permitame dejar algunas observacioens del código
Ejecutado en Ms Access VBA

En el encabezado se debe declarar la siguiente Private constante

Option Compare Database

Option Explicit

**Private Const NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = &H20&**

Trate de ejecutar un BAT ya creado usando cualquiera de estas 2 lineas y ninguna funcionó

*Execute "cmd.exe /c ""C:\temp\envio\SNP.bat", , True*

*Execute "cmd.exe /k ""C:\temp\envio\SNP.bat", , True*

Esta es la solucion, aqui se las dejo:

Al parecer la función por defecto corre en el directorio C:\temp\ del ejemplo

Se debe cambiar al directorio donde se encuentra el bat
usar un Change Directory (cd)

Usar esta línea:

**Execute "cmd.exe /c""cd C:\temp\envio & C:\temp\envio\SNP.bat", , True**

Saludos desde Colombia
Daniel Pino